# union of two strings

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



string s1="a,b,c"; //Set up string 1
string s2="b,v"; //Set up string 2
string s3; //Setup string 3
```

i try something to do with the union, could somebody help me how to resolve the errors.the function should make union of the strings but there is some problem.thanks

Comment: Can you convert them to sets first?

Comment: Have you tried at all? Show us the code for _your_ attempt.

Comment: If you are using C++, you can try the **string** type in std namespace

Comment: i am thinking of the structure of the algorithm but i need help for the code                                                                   1.copy open string into result
2.for each element in second string if it is not in the first one add to result

Comment: `sort(a.begin(), a.end()); sort(b.begin(), b.end()); string c; set_union(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), back_inserter(c));` using `<algorithm>` and `<iterator>`.

Comment: The example you provided isn't really a "union of two strings".  It's really a string corresponding to a union of two sets of _numbers_, where each set is expressed as a string.  Thinking about it this way may help you to formulate the answer.

Comment: the first string maybe  string A="Programing" string B="Program"  and the union string C="Programing" . I don't have the idea how to write this with  code...

Comment: @MIKI This doesn't seem to be well-definied.  What if A="Programing" and B="Prop".  Do you expect union to be "Propgraming", or "Programingp", or something else?

Comment: the result should be "Programingp",if you have any suggestion it would be very useful for me, thanks

Comment: @MIKI: Just to be clear. What you want is the union of two [mulisets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). Do you want to treat `,` as part of the multiset? In other words, do you want A=`a,b,c` B=`b,v` to result in C=`a,b,cv` or int C=`a,b,c,v` because if you want the latter then you should tokenize the input first.

Comment: I want , as a part of the multiset like this      C=a,b,c,v

Comment: "how to resolve the errors" - what errors? "but there is some problem" - define exactly what the problem is. There's a lot of folks trying to help you here much you're making this awfully hard for them to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the subobjects e.g. into a `std::vector<std::string>`, `std::sort()` them if they strings my be unsorted, then `std::set_union()` them, and then concatenate the result.

Comment: public string  union (string A, string B)                                                      {                                                                        code                                                                         }                                                                                        someone help how to write the code for this function which calculate union of two strings

Comment: Let's put it this way: I'm a professional programmer and have somewhat outgrown the need of doing homework assignments. I'm happy to comment on where your code, if you post some, might go wrong and/or giving hints on how to solve problems. Also, you should realize my solution wouldn't be accepted for a homework anyway.

Comment: +1, I didn't know that `std::set_union()` was [generalized for multisets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195973/set-union-with-multiset-containers). You learn something new everyday.

Comment: As a first note: **don't** repeat in a comment what the code does! This **will** fall out of sync with the actual implementation. Instead, say what a function is doing semantically and, possibly, how it dos this. Next, **don't** use global variables! There are very few reasons to do so and in all cases I'm aware of they would definitely be constant. There still **very** few cases where this is the right thing to do.

Comment: Your first loop assigns each character to `c`. How does this help? `c` can only store one character. Your second loop wants to be inside your first loop: you go need to go to the second loop, trying to find the current `c` and append `c` if it is not found at all (i.e. you need to add `c` if the inner loop finished without finding `c` in the string `s3`. However, you also don't want to operate on characters but on "words": you need to find the next comma and extract the word between the current position and the next position.

Answer (score 0):

Split both strings into their elements, put the elements in a std::set