# Given sequence of different length find the largest sequence of numbers common to every one of them

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a problem for which I have tried a lot of ideas but could not find an optimal solution.

The problem is this:

Given a sequence of n numbers all sorted in increasing order but of different lengths, find the largest subsequence common to each one of them.

For examples let's say there are 3 sequences A, B and C,

where

```
A = {1 3 5 7 9 10 11 15 30 43 44 45 50}
B = {1 2 3 7 8 10 11 12 23 27 30 38 40 41 45 50 51 53 }
C = {0 1 3 7 9 11 12 13 14 19 20 24 28 30  50 51 61 90 99}
```

So the largest common subsequence to all of them is:

```
Answer = {1 3 7 11 30 50}
```

The above example illustrates the idea I am trying to convey. How can I find such a largest common subsequence which is all in increasing order?

Thanks for your time and consideration to read this post. I will be really thankful if you could also offer suggestions.

Comment: Mostly like `merge` is done.

Comment: Like @Jarod42 suggests do it the same way as merge step is done in mergesort and you can do this with worst case complexity of O(n*k), where n is length of longest sequence and k is number of sequences. Can't get better than linear in this case I think.

Comment: I am asking for suggestion to solve this problem, not the complete solution

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota if one sequence is much shorter than the others, it might be faster to: go over the shortest sequence, binary search for each element in the other sequences.

Comment: @Beginner, because the OP didn't show any attempt in solving his task; instead he just dumped it on us "as is". Compare "Hi, here is the problem which I couldnt solve. How do I solve it?" with "Hi, here is the problem, I tried doing < this and that > but my solution doesn't work in < this case >, how do I make it work?"

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall ok, fair enough. Just claiming "I tried a lot" is not good enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple solution: you can merge all the sets (linear complexity) an then count the numbers which occur n times in the final set (again linear complexity).

Use std::multiset (to have duplicates) and [merge in algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/).

Try it out [here](http://ideone.com/bQAOC7):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::multiset<int> a {1,2,3};
    std::multiset<int> b {1,2,3};

    std::multiset<int> result;
    merge( a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(),  
    std::inserter(result, result.begin()));
    std::cout<<result.size()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

> Success   time: 0 memory: 16064 signal:0
>
> 6

The set-union semantics extend to multiset (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195973/set-union-with-multiset-containers)) but not in the way I always tought they [would](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/8-2.html).

> The operation of taking the union of two multisets should be
>   distinguished from the operation of merging two sets. Imagine that one
>   argument set contains three instances of the element 7, and the second
>   set contains two instances of the same value. The union will contain
>   only three such values, while the merge will contain five.

From the standard, 25.3.5:

> The semantics of the set operations are generalised to multisets in a standard way by defining union() to contain the maximum number of
>   occurrences of every element, intersection() to contain the minimum,
>   and so on.

Comment: Look at the example in the set_union reference. It removes duplicates.

Comment: @yassin set_union semantics extend to multiset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195973/set-union-with-multiset-containers

Comment: sorry, didn't know that :)

Comment: @yassin no problem, I should have mentioned it

Comment: "If any equivalent values appeared n times in the first range and m times in the second, std::merge would output all n+m occurrences whereas std::set_union would output std::max(n, m) ones only." from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union

Comment: So if an element has 1 occurence in A, 1 in B, 1 in C, the output will be 1 time that element. If it has 2 occurences in A, 1 in B, 1 in C, the output will be 2 times that element. That's not what we want, right?

Comment: @yassin I tried it and YOU ARE RIGHT! Wow, I really did lean something here.